# ASP.Net web api return image and text together

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webapi

I am looking for an example of returning text and image in the same HTTP get message. I have seen returning files and seen complex objects but not any with both text and image in the same response.

Answer (score 0):

---

Please try this code 
You can get the image name,text and Image path from you GET APi call

```
public byte[] GetImage(int componentId)
{
            using (var dashboardService = new DashboardService())
            {
                var component = dashboardService.GetImage(componentId);
                var context = HttpContext.Current;
                string filePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + component.ImageName);
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(1, 1);
                        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                        byte[] byteImage = memoryStream.ToArray();
                        return byteImage;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this out today.